# What SQL-based server software should I install locally to develop db skills using?

Tags: sql, ms-access, installation, local, osx-lion

I'm currently working a contract for a company which will be moving an access database to MS SQL server in the future, and I'd like to hone my skills before the company makes the switch.

I'm also looking forward to possibly developing a rudimentary website which would have a simple HTML/CSS/JS front end, and those skills could also use a sharpening. I'd like to develop my skills through some SQL work locally on my home computer. Researching how to do that has only yielded the suggestion of installing an Apache web server with PHP and MySQL on my local machine. While I'm not opposed to doing that, the last time I worked with an Apache install, it was over-complicated and bloated.

Is there a more streamlined option? It doesn't seem necessary to load an entire web server for the specific use I'm going for.

I'd prefer to simply install a program that allows me to host the [My]SQL database locally, and perhaps later some way to test HTML and Javascript interacting with the database. I'm already somewhat familiar with [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com). As an added bonus, my Python skills are rusty and I'd like to get used to scripting Python. At this point Xcode (4.2) seems the likely solution here, but I'm open to other options.

I would be installing on a 11" MacBook Air running Lion and Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just installed MySQL. I ended up following the instructions available from [this blog post](http://www.djangoapp.com/blog/2011/07/24/installation-of-mysql-server-on-mac-os-x-lion/) about setting up django, but not installing phpMyAdmin...

[This post](http://techxplorer.com/2011/03/03/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x/) also has some good things about setting up passwords and such, since I really didn't want to be stuck relying on something else to admin the MySQL setup.

Answer (score 0):

Apache and PHP ship with Mac OS X 10.7.  MySQL installation is pretty straightforward with the package available from MySQL.
Take a look at [these instructions](http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/)--for your purposes, you can stop after the `php.ini` section.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a very subjective question.

I find CherryPy (with Python) for the web server and server programming, combined with jQuery to augment the HTML in the browser to be a powerful and lightweight combination.  When possible, I use SQLite for the database — another extremely lightweight option.  I share your distaste for Apache, at least when it's not needed.

If you want to develop solid skills that are peculiar to MS SQL Server, you really don't have much alternative to installing SQL Server someplace you can access it.  Although you can certainly limit your use of SQL Server to standard SQL set-based commands SQL Server is more often used with a heavy emphasis on procedural code built into stored procedures.  Those skills (writing SQL Server specific stored procedures) are only very minimally transferable to or from other database products.

Answer (score 0):

If you were running Windows, you could get MS SQL Server Express for free:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

Comment: Or Developer edition for about $40: much better for developing skills unless you are targetting SQL Express. Or get by for quite a while with the SQL 2012 CTP and Betas.